# How to I convert my props data into an array in my React with Redux project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, redux, react-redux

In my solution which is an ASP.NET Core project with React, Redux, and Kendo React Components I need to return my props as an array.  I'm using the Kendo Dropdown widget as below.

```
<DropDownList data={this.props.vesseltypes} />
```

However I receive the error of :

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to
>   `DropDownList`, expected `array`.

So, I checked my returned data from the `props.vesseltypes` which is an array of as opposed to a flat array.

[image: Array of Objects]

Here is my code for how this data is returned:

**components/vessels/WidgetData.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionCreators } from '../../store/Types';
import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';

class WidgetData extends Component {
componentWillMount() {        
    this.props.requestTypes();      
}
render() {
    console.log(this.props.vesseltypes)
    return (
            <div>
                <DropDownList data={this.props.vesseltypes} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect(
    vesseltypes => vesseltypes,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(WidgetData);
```

**components/store/Types.js**

```
const requestVesselTypes = 'REQUEST_TYPES';
const receiveVesselTypes = 'RECEIVE_TYPES';
const initialState = {
    vesseltypes: [],
    isLoading: false
};

export const actionCreators = {
    requestTypes: () => async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: requestVesselTypes });

        const url = 'api/KendoData/GetVesselTypes';
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const alltypes = await response.json();

        dispatch({ type: receiveVesselTypes, alltypes });
    }   
}
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    if (action.type === requestVesselTypes) {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }
    if (action.type === receiveVesselTypes) {
        alltypes = action.alltypes;
        return {
            ...state,
            vesseltypes: action.alltypes,
            isLoading: false
        }
    }    
    return state;
};
```

And finally, the reducer is defined in the store

**components/store/configureStore.js**

```
const reducers = {
    vesseltypes: Types.reducer
};
```

**Controllers/KendoDataController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetVesselTypes()
    {
        var types = _vesselTypeService.GetVesselTypes();

        return Json(types);
    }
```

So, the dropdown widget expects an array, what I return via the store is an array of objects. As such, this can't be used by the dropdown because it's not what it is expecting.  My question is, how do I return this as a single array or flat array?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `this.props.vesseltypes.vesseltypes` or you are not passing `null` there at init?

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Kendo, but I can tell you that all thats happening is that you get an array of Objects from the Kendo api and the store returns said array of Objects. These Obejcts on the array contain various information, which menas that you can't simply convert them to arrays themselves. What kind of information should be passed to the dropdown? You either have to send properly formated data from the Kendo API or you have to pick the Information you wan't to show and transform the Array of Objects to an flat array yourself, preferably in the reducer.

Answer (score 2):

First deconstruct the part that you want to map to a property from your state:

```
export default connect(
  ({vesseltypes}) => ({vesseltypes}),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(WidgetData);
```

Then you could just map vesselTypes to an array of strings, since that's what **[Kendo DropdownList](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/)** seems to expect:

```
<div>
  <DropDownList data={this.props.vesseltypes.map((vessel) => vessel.TypeName)} />
</div>
```

Which should result in what you wanted to achieve.

Alternatively you could look into how to implement a HOC to map your objects to values, it's specified in the [Kendo docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/common-scenarios/#toc-using-data-fields-for-values), or you can checkout the [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cmnvbd) they've prepared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to extract vesselTypes from the response here

```
const alltypes = await response.json();
```

and your console.log shows that, it contains whole response not just vesselTypes array.

EDIT: On top of that your connect seems wrong, you just pass whole state as a prop not extracting the part you need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need an array of strings where the value is in key `TypeName`.
First of all, I would suggest renaming your variables, if there isn't any back-end restriction like how it's returned via fetch.
For example, these:

```
alltypes => allTypes
vesseltypes => vesselTypes
```

Regarding the issue, you just need to do a quick transform before passing data into component. Not sure how the drop down component uses the original input data but I would reduce the array into separate variable to create it only once.

Then pass the variable `vesselTypeList` into component `DropDownList`.

Last thing is where to do this transform, when result has been retrieved and Redux updates your props via `mapStateToProps` first argument of `connect` function.

```
const getTypeList = (vesseltypes) => {
  return vesseltypes.reduce((result, item) => {
    result.push(item.TypeName);
    return result;
  }, []);
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ vesseltypes }) => { vesseltypes: getTypeList(vesseltypes) };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(WidgetData);
```